# Add new item to list of dictionaries controlling based on other item values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries containing a household id (HID) for each year:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'HID':'1','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'1','year':'2018'},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2018'},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2018'}]
```

I want to read in each dict and add a new numeric id. I can do something similar to this using the following code:

```
i = 0
for line in list_of_dicts:
    line['id'] = i

    i += 1
```

However, this make the `id` item run continuously like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'HID':'1','year':'2017','id':1},
                 {'HID':'1','year':'2018','id':2},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2017','id':3},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2018','id':4},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2017','id':5},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2018','id':6}]
```

I want to allocate the same numeric `id` variable to each HID across each year, like so:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'HID':'1','year':'2017','id':1},
                 {'HID':'1','year':'2018','id':1},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2017','id':2},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2018','id':2},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2017','id':3},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2018','id':3}]
```

How do I control id allocation to be the same for each household, for each year?

Comment: change `line['id'] = i` to `line['id'] = line['hid']`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to not be based off `i`. Instead do this:

```
for line in list_of_dicts:
    line['id'] = line['hid']
```

That way you create a new entry `id` based off the `hid` for that line

Comment: If I understand this correctly Chrispresso, this would have made the id equal to the hid, but this isn't ideal. In the reprex I gave the id started from 1, but in the actual data it doesn't work like that, so I've gone with the answer from Ajax. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, you can use a list comprehension and dictionary unpacking:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'HID':'1','year':'2017'},
             {'HID':'1','year':'2018'},
             {'HID':'2','year':'2017'},
             {'HID':'2','year':'2018'},
             {'HID':'3','year':'2017'},
             {'HID':'3','year':'2018'}]
new_data = [{**i, **{'id':i['HID']}} for i in list_of_dicts]
```

Output:

```
[{'HID': '1', 'year': '2017', 'id': '1'}, {'HID': '1', 'year': '2018', 'id': '1'}, {'HID': '2', 'year': '2017', 'id': '2'}, {'HID': '2', 'year': '2018', 'id': '2'}, {'HID': '3', 'year': '2017', 'id': '3'}, {'HID': '3', 'year': '2018', 'id': '3'}]
```

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
list_of_dicts = [{'HID':'1','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'1','year':'2018'},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'2','year':'2018'},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2017'},
                 {'HID':'3','year':'2018'}]
for line in list_of_dicts:
    line['id'] = line['HID']

print(list_of_dicts)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'HID': '1', 'year': '2017', 'id': '1'}, {'HID': '1', 'year': '2018', 'id': '1'}, {'HID': '2', 'year': '2017', 'id': '2'}, {'HID': '2', 'year': '2018', 'id': '2'}, {'HID': '3', 'year': '2017', 'id': '3'}, {'HID': '3', 'year': '2018', 'id': '3'}]
```

Comment: You can get rid of `i` entirely since it's not used anywhere